# Should I use @2x or -hd?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am confused on the differences between using @2x or -hd
Is one more efficient or quicker than the other?
I am using Cocos2D.

Comment: Stupid question, but what does -hd do?  I've always used @2X for retina display images (and I think the capitalization is important there), but I've never seen the -hd part before.

Comment: Capitalization may be important; I've only ever seen "@2x" (small x) in practice.

Comment: @RonLugge "-hd" is the suffix used on Cocos2D for high resolution images. (I edited my comment because I misread yours)

Comment: Regarding capitalization, I may be in error -- or outdated.  The guides I read way-back-when were practically non-existant (IOS 4... or was it 3?... had JUST come out), and I've just used @2X since because that was what we managed to get working in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty neither is quicker than the other

In my case, since I like using Cocos together with UIKit, I use the -hd suffix for all the Cocos related images (textures and such), and @2x for images that will be used with UIKit.

Comment: The cocos2d wiki warns that there may be issues when using @2x with cocos2d. Though it doesn't say what these issues are.

Answer (score 1):

`@2x` is used before `CCDirector` is loaded..so the `@2x` is a **must** for the loading screen and icons

if the `CCDirector` is already loaded (aka..you're in game) you can use either `@2x` or `-hd` but if i remember corectly `-hd` is slightly slower and you have to enable retina display in app delegate... remove comments of:

```
if (![director enableRetinDisplay:YES]) CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

you don't need to enable retina display if you're using `@2x`

Answer (score -4):

Like the other poster, I've never heard of an "-hd" suffix for image names in iOS.

Where did you see that? App names for retina devices or for the iPad sometimes have -hd as part of the name, but as far as I know there's no formal meaning to a "-hd" suffix in iOS.

You should set up your program to use standard images. To support Retina devices, you should save 2 versions of each image, "anImage.png", and "anImage@2x.png", where the one with the @2x suffix is twice as big in height and in width.

Comment: If you don't know what he's talking about, then why answer? Like I said on the comments, "-hd" is the suffix used on Cocos2D for high resolution images.

Comment: My mistake. I missed the bit about cocos2d (or maybe that was added in an edit after I posted?) I was pretty confident that -hd had no meaning in Apple's frameworks.